# Azure WebHook not saving

Tags: azure, webhooks, azure-automation

I have just set up an Azure Webhook:
[image]

But after I enter the info about the web hook, it looks like it has saved it:
[image]

But when I look at my list of web hooks, there is nothing there:
[image]

I have cleared my cache and cookies and have also tried in IE.

When I try to hit the end point with a POST, just to see if in fact it did get set up, I get nothing:
[image]

Any ideas?

thanks
Russ

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yesterday, Azure Automation released a change that broke the ability to link schedules or webhooks to runbooks with **mandatory** parameters.  We are working on a fix for this right now and are planning to have it deployed this week.

As a work around until we get this fix in, you can remove any mandatory parameters and either include them as variables in your runbook or optional parameters (`[parameter(Mandatory=$false)]`).

Comment: Azure Automation has released a fix for this.  You can now create webhooks and schedules with mandatory parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Did you hit the OK button on the bottom of the Add Webhook blade? This is needed to create the webhook.

Comment: this is all working now and I think it was a bug in the portal or a cache issue. I have now got Web Hooks working and use them to stop and start some VMs. thanks Russ